# Searching for an account by accountId

Tags: java, error-handling

I have a piece of code that is fetching account objects from a service

```
    private Account searchAccount(String accountId) {
    try {
        Account account = service.search(accountId);
        return account;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("searchAccount failed", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

After some thought I feel it could be refactored as:

```
    private Account searchAccount(String accountId) {
    Account account = null;
    try {
        account = service.search(accountId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("searchAccount failed", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return account;
}
```

Apart from coding style technically, which one has more pros and what would be cons of using multiple return statements in a method?

Comment: There is not much context given, is this the only code you're looking to have reviewed? Typically a question on this site will have several relevant classes rather than just one method...

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of best practice and if someone could come up with a scenario where code would not behave well when there are multiple returns points

Comment: I have downvoted this question, holding off on a close vote for now. If your question is "what's the best practice regarding X?", per our [help/on-topic] it's explicitly off-topic on this site. Good CR questions involve your real actual working code, that answerers usually review against best coding practices.

Comment: [Which refactoring rule](http://refactoring.com/catalog/), specifically, are you talking about? You shouldn't use the term "refactor" when you just mean "rewrite".

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks for pointing it out, this question is around actual code and not around a best practice in general

Comment: Although this may be actual code, without context about what the surrounding code does, and what this code accomplishes (in plain English), I find it difficult for anyone to provide a very meaningful review, hence, "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: you are asking us to review `account = service.search(accountId);` inside a Try Catch statement, but we don't know what that does.  this is still very unclear as to what the code does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea of having only a [single point of exit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from) is somewhat antiquated. The only real advantage is that it makes it easier to add additional stuff right before exiting, such as <strike>cleaning up resources or</strike> adding debug statements.

Personally, I prefer having multiple returns, as it makes it really explicit what will be returned (but of course you should not overdo it; if your method is extremely long with a ton of returns, something would obviously not be right).

As to your actual code, I would rewrite it slightly:

```
private Account searchAccount(String accountId) {
    try {
        return service.search(accountId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("searchAccount failed", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }    
}
```

Note that I removed the unnecessary temporary variable, and that I moved the null return into the catch statement to make it more explicit in which cases null will be returned.

You should also think about your general approach. Returning null for control flow can result in somewhat ugly code after a while, as you will have a lot of null checks in the calling code. Personally, I would prefer to just throw the exception (an invalid id seems like an exceptional case).

Comment: In Java, the finally-block more than covers the end-of-routine cleanup concerns....

Comment: this is not a good place to swallow an exception, the exception might not be just an invalid ID, if it were then that specific exception should be caught and the rest should crash the application.

Answer (score 3):

From your use of `log.error()`, I surmise that an exception in `service.search()` is an error. By catching the exception and returning `null`, you've taken a useful tool for directing flow of control and made it worse.

The caller now must test whether the result of `searchAccount()` is `null`.  If it forgets to check, then that would just trigger a `NullPointerException`, which is probably more difficult to debug than the original exception.  If it remembers to check, and detects a `null`, then it doesn't know whether it means that the `accountId` really doesn't exist or the lookup mechanism failed (e.g. the database is unavailable).

Therefore, you should either:

- allow the original exception to propagate
- log and rethrow the same exception
- log and throw a wrapped exception

As a bonus, you eliminate your multiple-return dilemma entirely.  (It wasn't a real concern to begin with.  There's nothing wrong with multiple returns.  *Nothing at all.*)

I would add that if you call `log.error(…)`, you should not do `e.printStackTrace()`.  If you want to see the stack trace, then configure your logging mechanism to show it.